# POSTMAN - EXPRESS - Modify JSON before writing to file

Tags: javascript, json, express, postman

I have written a POSTMAN call to a server that responds with a list of items in JSON like below:-

```
{
    "count": 6909,
    "setIds": [
        "1/7842/0889#001",
        "2/4259/0166#001",
        "ENT0730/0009",
        "9D/11181#002",
        "1/9676/0001#001",
        "2/4718/0001#004",
        "2/1783/0044#001",
        "1/4501/0001#001",
        "1/2028/0002#002",
        "2/3120/0079#001",
        "2/1672/0024#001",
        "2/3398/0064#001"
}
```

I want to make calls to another server using the value of the setID each time and iterate through all of these so that I end up calling the server thousands of times to verify the response from that server. The problem I have is that the second server expects the set id to be in a form where the forward slashes are converted to underscores and the hashes to dots, so

`"1/7842/0889#001"`

becomes

`"1_7842_0889.001"`

I have code that converts one to the other in POSTMAN

```
   var jsonData = pm.response.json()

    for (var i=0; i<jsonData.setIds.length; i++)
    {
    var new_j = jsonData.setIds[i].replace (/#/g, ".");
    var new_i = new_j.replace (/\//g, "_");
    }
})
```

This works fine line by line it creates the right thing in the console of POSTMAN but obviously what I really need to do is save the entire JSON in the right form to a file and then read from that file line by line using the corrected data. I don't seem to be able to save the data in a file in the right form using my code and I suspect I am missing something simple. Is there a way to write a file line by line from in side postman or in a script and manipulate the data as I'm creating it?

Alternatively I guess I could read from the JSON I have saved i.e. the full response and iterate through that manipulating the data as a pre-request script?

I have tried to do something like this using environmental variables - so in my first call I do:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('setIds', JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

and then in my second call to the express server where I want to send my payload I run a pre-request script that I thought would work using the env variable but this fails as it doesn't seem to like the {...

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

I think there are probably some neat ways of solving this either doing all of this outside of POSTMAN in javascript but I'm a little lost where to start. Any help appreciated

Comment: your question is unreadable - please fix formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would tell you are plaing with content, but not setting it back to JSON object ??

jsonData.setIds[i] = new_i;

can help or you can use 2x replace it in a string and convert back to make it easier (in case there are no / or # somewhere else).

```js
var src = {
    "count": 6909,
    "setIds": [
        "1/7842/0889#001",
        "2/4259/0166#001",
        "ENT0730/0009",
        "9D/11181#002",
        "1/9676/0001#001",
        "2/4718/0001#004",
        "2/1783/0044#001",
        "1/4501/0001#001",
        "1/2028/0002#002",
        "2/3120/0079#001",
        "2/1672/0024#001",
        "2/3398/0064#001"
        //...
    ]
}
var str = JSON.stringify(src, null, 4);
str = str.replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/#/g,'.');
console.log(str);
var res = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(res);
```